# On click add class to element with certain class and remove it from all other elements with same class

Tags: javascript, jquery

Basically I am trying to figure out the following I have several elements like

```
<a href="#" clas="v-bar"></a>
<a href="#" clas="v-bar"></a>
<a href="#" clas="v-bar"></a>
<a href="#" clas="v-bar"></a>
<a href="#" clas="v-bar"></a>
```

I need to figure out how to add class to an element when it is clicked, so for example add `.v-current` , but at the same time remove it from all other elements with a class of `.v-bar` ? All with jQuery.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('.v-bar').click(function(e){
    $('.v-bar').removeClass('v-current');
    $(this).addClass('v-current');
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.v-bar').click(function(){
    $('.v-current').removeClass('v-current');
    $(this).addClass('v-current');
});
```